Why do we ban renaming of free variables?
I have read this Q&A, but it didn't completely clear up my confusion. It is about substitution and not renaming. I agree with that substitution cannot be allowed freely, because it would allow for situations where the meaning is changed. The same is true for renaming, but just like with substitution, renaming can be allowed for free variables if it is restricted in much the same way that substitution is restricted for free variables.
According to this article, you are not allowed to rename free variables at all. When I first read it, it made no sense to me, though after the Q&A above, I realized it probably had to do with variable names colliding. In a sentence like $\forall x( P(x) \land Q(y))$, renaming $y$ to $x$ would change the meaning.
But one can easily avoid this by simply restricting variable renaming for free variables:

All free occurrences of a free variable $x$ can be renamed to an expression containing $y$ so long as none of the occurrences lay within the scope of a quantifier adjacent to a $y$.

However, perhaps it is merely easier to outright ban renaming of free variables? I would agree, but I want to know for sure that is the reason behind the ban. Also, I see that my proposal for restricted renaming would just be a subtype of substitution, since one can substitute a free variable with an expression containing another free variable (so long as there is no capture). Given that, I guess my proposal is already in effect, just as a specific kind of substitution. This is fine, though in my head it seems more prudent to  use different words to separate substitution of free variables with other (expressions of) free variables from substitution of free variables with constants, since the former does not yield definite truth values, whereas the latter does. The first is essentially renaming, whereas the latter is variable assignment.
So, my question is basically whether or not the paragraph below is true:
You cannot "rename" free variables, because we want to avoid variable names colliding.  But, you can essentially rename free variables through substitution, if you substitute the free variable with (an expression of) some other free variable.

Suppose that, in a proof, we have a sub-proof  that introduces $x$ as a free variable. I see no problem with reintroducing $x$ in another sub-proof of that proof provided both are sufficiently "isolated" from one another, e.g. by the discharging of assumptions. Is that what you are getting at?

@DanChristensen I would have no problem with that, given that it is necessary to reuse symbols (given our limited alphabet). But that regards the topic of using the same name for different variables. Here I am talking about why we cannot rename a free variable within a formula.

Rules like "no renaming free variables" are not universal.  There are many different logics and many different ways of treating variables in logics.  Whatever particular reason someone has insisted on not renaming free variables, it will depend on what logic you are using.

@user110391 Even if you could, why would you want to do rename a free variable within a single formula? Wouldn't it cause unnecessary confusion?

@DanChristensen In order to make a formula clean, to increase its clarity. We can do that by renaming bound variables, but in some cases, that might be more cumbersome than just renaming free variables, if one could (using the restricted renaming described above).

@user110391 I don't understand. Please clarify with an example of this renaming process being applied to a formula. I can see renaming bound variables in a formula, but not the free variables.

Some comments
Wrt "In a sentence like $∀x(P(x) ∧ Q(y))$, renaming $y$  to $x$  would change the meaning", the issue has been discussed extensively in the linked post.
This is the case of the "free for" limitation: the occurence of $y$ in the formula is not free for $x$, exactly because if you "rename" the occurrence of $y$ with $x$ the new occurrence of $x$ will be inside the scope of the quantifier $\forall x$, while in the original formula there were no quantifier binding the occurrence of $y$.
This is the gist of the statement of slide 4 of the Lectures: "bound variables only play a
dummy role and can be replaced (with care!) by one another."
Wrt substitution, see last page of the Lectures:

renaming and substitution are different operations: renaming always acts on bound variables, while substitution always acts on free variables.
Also, renamings preserve the formula up to logical equivalence, while substitutions do not.

This means that the "transformation" of $∀x(P(x) ∧ Q(y))$ into $∀z(P(z) ∧ Q(y))$ causes no harm.
It does not say that substitution is forbidden, because it is not. Substitution - $A[t/y]$ in symbols is allowed in general, but if we do not consider the "free from" proviso we can change the meaning of the formula: "logical equivalence is not preserved".
But we can perform e.g. the substitution $∀x(P(x) ∧ Q(y))[z/y]$ and what we get is $∀x(P(x) ∧ Q(z))$.
Where we can get into trouble? In the context of a derivation, where the variable $z$ has been already used free.

The article you cite makes a distinction between renaming and substitution. It uses renaming to refer to the semantically harmless operation of changing the name of a bound variable. It uses substitution to refer to the operation of replacing a free varable in an expression with an arbitrary term, which might be a variable.
What you are thinking of as "renaming" a bound variable is not disallowed by the article, but just an instance of the more general operation that it calls substitution: you can't rename $x$ as $1 + 2$ in $\forall x (x < x + 1)$, but you can substitute $1 + 2$ for $x$ in $x < x + 1,$ to get the result $1 + 2 < (1 + 2) + 1.$
If you are doing a substitution where the substitute has free variables, then you may need to rename bound variables to preserve the correct meaning: to substitute $y + 1$ for $x$ in $\exists y(x \le y)$, you have to rename the bound variable $y$ to preserve the expected semantics: you want the result to be the true expression $\exists z (y + 1 \le z)$, not the false expression $\exists y(y + 1 \le y)$.

@ryang: thanks for the improvements.

Usually, especially in mathematical logic, the notion of free variable is characterised though the notion of bound variable or adequacy for a truth-value, thus as if it were merely an intermediate stage before forming a sentence (i.e., closed formula).
In order to assess the function of logical free variables in a broader perspective, let us consider an example from outside of mathematics:

If Lee Oswald had not killed John F. Kennedy, someone else would have
done it.

In this statement, "someone else" is a typical free variable. Who is "someone else"? It might be anybody whoever.
But it might be nobody as well, since the statement does not assert existential import (contrast this to $\exists x\phi(x)$).
One of our priorities in logic is to keep track of terms. Thus, the operation of renaming variables (α-conversion in lambda calculus) is only a syntactical fallback, to arrange the argument properly without doing something logically illegitimate.
With bound variables, there is no risk on this, for each variable is assessed within the scope of the quantifier by which it is bound.
As for free variables, it is easier to lose track of the reference of the term (viz., "somone else" in the example) when alphabetically vary its representation. Hence, it is always safer to rename the bound variables in case of need.
It should go without saying that, a substitution (which is a syntactical operation) that changes the semantic status of a free variable is illegitimate, for the very characteristic of free variable is that it is semantically indeterminate (whether it occurs by itself or within an open term).
